# Upload wxImage with wxHTTP Post request

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How can I upload an image stored in wxImage or wxBitmap with a wxHTTP POST request?
I know I can do it somehow with:

```
wxImage::SaveFile (wxOutputStream &stream, wxBitmapType type) and
wxHTTP::SetPostBuffer (const wxString &contentType, const wxMemoryBuffer &data)
```

But I just started with cpp an wx.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The missing piece is some class implementing the `wxOutputStream` interface, whose content you could then send using the `SetPostBuffer()` method.

You can see all provided implementations of `wxOutputStream` [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_output_stream.html). It seems that you are looking for [`wxMemoryOutputStream`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_memory_output_stream.html).

The full code part therefore would be something like this:

```
wxMemoryOutputStream stream;
if (!myImage.SaveFile(stream, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
    ;// TODO: Handle error
SetPostBuffer("image/png", *stream.GetOutputStreamBuffer());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. A bit more verbose, but minus the error checking... 
The member vars are wxURLs.

```
  // ok now read the data into a buffer again
  wxMemoryBuffer buf;
  {
    // don't have charBuf around for too long
    wxFile f(someFileName);
    char charBuf[f.Length()];
    f.Read(charBuf, f.Length());
    buf.AppendData(charBuf, f.Length());
  }

  // upload!
  wxHTTP post; 

  post.SetPostBuffer("application/gzip", buf);

  post.Connect(mDestUrl.GetServer()):

  wxInputStream *iStream = post.GetInputStream(mDestUrl.GetPath() + "?" + mDestUrl.GetQuery());

  // put result into stream
  wxString res;
  wxStringOutputStream oStream(&res);
  iStream->Read(oStream);

  wxLogDebug(TAG " server replied: " + res);
```

Note that wxHttp does not do a multipart upload. In PHP,for instance, you can access the data via

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```